# AutoFilter without using Range

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm trying to filter a column in a worksheet based on a specific value using [autofilter](/questions/tagged/autofilter). But the workbook which I'm supposed to filter data in is generated dynamically so I don't know what to put in Range().

However, I do know the position of this column (as in "3rd from dynamically generated column").

Can anyone please tell me how I can use [autofilter](/questions/tagged/autofilter) when I only know the column number?

Comment: The first argument to `autofilter` is Field which is the column number, so if you simply filter the whole sheet (using UsedRange) you can specify the column number if you know it.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the auto filter on the column then. `range("A1").autofilter`

change the A to what ever column you need. Selecting the range and the first cell will pull all in a filter that column that is connected. So it will filter all up to any blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter the entire column, don't worry about ranges.

```
   Columns("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="a"
```